# vscode extension - How to log keystrokes

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am doing user testing for a `vscode extension` (for some university project) and I need to get a log of the keys that are pressed in the text editor.

I have tried with `onDidChangeTextDocument`, but that doesn't capture keystrokes that don't modify the document (for instance, Ctrl or Alt). I have also tried to add an event listener to the active text editor like so:

```
vscode.window.activeTextEditor.addEventListener(('keydown', event => {
  console.log(`KeyboardEvent: ${event.key || event.keyCode}`)
}))
```

but it doesn't look like `activeTextEditor` allows to add such function.

Does anyone know if vscode allows to listen for keystrokes?

Comment: also check https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/vim-sample

Comment: For reference, there is a keylogger extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=phil294.keylogger but as you said, it doesn't log modifier keys

Answer (score 2):

`vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument(handleChange)` handles any change in the document. By this even you can get th ekeystrokes. Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727520/capturing-keystrokes-in-visual-studio-code-extension#answer-36753622)

Comment: this works for keyUp not keyDown, which means the text u will get will be the modified not the original

Answer (score 1):

VS Code does not expose keypress events to extension directly. Try reviewing VS Code's [api guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api) and think about if you can accomplish what you are after in a different way.

However, the closest approximation to `keydown` in VS Code is that an extension can register for the `type` command in VS Code: `vscode.commands.registerCommand('type', e => ...)`

This command will fire for keypresses. However it [does not log modifier keys directly](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5280). The `type` command should also only be used for debugging or in very specific cases as it has performance problems and [major limitations](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13441)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem myself.

**The Visual Studio Code API seems to not offer such functionality**, even the 'type' debugging command is not reliable.

Instead I found out that for logging keystrokes the best solution is to **spawn a child process from within the extension code that handles keylogging**. Using a python script with the [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) packet you can capture presses and releases of any key (special/modifier keys included) and save them to a .csv or feed them back to your extension with IPC. Using the [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) packet can provide you with the title of the window in focus so you can filter keystrokes based on if they were issued inside the Visual Studio Code window or not.

Javascript Extension Code:

```
const vscode = require('vscode');
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

function activate(context) {
    const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["Total/Path/To/keylogger.py"]);
}
```

Python Key Logging Example Code:

```
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetForegroundWindow
import keyboard

def my_callback(event):
    name=event.name
    timestamp=event.time
    event_type=event.event_type
    log=name + "," + event_type +","+timestamp+","+ GetWindowText(GetForegroundWindow())
    with open("Total/Path/To/log.csv",'a',encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write('\n'+log)

keyboard.hook(callback=my_callback)
keyboard.wait()
```