# How can I have CSS automatically formatted so that all of the properties are in order by length, as I type?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

Let's say I have CSS like this:

```css
.community-item .suggestion-highlight, .is-flashing, .suggestion-highlight, .cm-s-obsidian span.obsidian-search-match-highlight {
    background: var(--highlightColor);
    font-weight: inherit;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0 1px;
}
```

and I create a new line below `padding`, and I typed this out: `color: var(--text-on-accent) !important;`. It would be longer than all the properties already written. I want it so as I type that out, it like goes up each line as it surpasses the line above it in length, until it reaches the top. Like this

```css
.community-item .suggestion-highlight, .is-flashing, .suggestion-highlight, .cm-s-obsidian span.obsidian-search-match-highlight {
    background: var(--highlightColor);
    font-weight: inherit;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0 1px;
    color: var(--te
}

.community-item .suggestion-highlight, .is-flashing, .suggestion-highlight, .cm-s-obsidian span.obsidian-search-match-highlight {
    background: var(--highlightColor);
    font-weight: inherit;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: var(--tex
    padding: 0 1px;
}
```

And then reaches the top, above `background`. I know this isn't what professional web developers would do, it may not be good practice, but that's how I prefer to sort properties. This is my personal CSS.

Comment: I never seen such a rule, this seems purely estetic, not necessarily improving readability. I think there's no automatic way of doing this, also, having the lines move automatically while you type would be annoying for most developers.
If you are on Windows or Linux you can move lines around by holding Alt (Option on Mac), then pressing arrow up or down will move the line up or down.

Comment: The length of the whole line.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt that such a specific thing exists, but you might be able to achieve something like this by creating an extension that listens to keypresses and performs action accordingly. This question about listening to keypresses in vs-code active text editor could be a good place to begin: [vscode extension - How to log keystrokes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57561242/vscode-extension-how-to-log-keystrokes)

In that same question user [@ctf0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3574919/ctf0) also posted this example that could be useful: [how vim emulation could be implemented in a VS Code extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/vim-sample)

I would have posted this as a comment, as this is not a concrete solution, but I lack the nesesary reputation.